# Averaging a set range of cell values based on a separate cell value

Tags: excel

Trying to return an average based on a finite set of values in a range.  The range starting point is determined by a separate cell value.

If Cell A1 = 3/1/15
I need the average of values beginning with 3/1/15 column, and extending 12 columns.

Starting date in A2, Avg in B2, List of Date headers in C1:Z1, cell values underneath headers columns.

---

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hDPPIWKFUbKiUNvwbbY-6lFp18ujderwgaFSa9OqMEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you mocked up some data and posted the data in your original post as text.

Comment: Does that link work? Sorry, I can't figure out how to do a table in the post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `AVERAGEIFS` function, so in cell B2 to calculate the average of cells C2 to Q2 if they are between the value in A2 and 365 days on from the value in A2:

(Adapted using comment from @Scott)

`=AVERAGEIFS(C2:Q2,$C$1:$Q$1,">="&A2,$C$1:$Q$1,"<"&A2+365)`

Comment: Thank you,  I want to limit it to the next 12 columns. Can that be accommodated through AVERAGEIFS?

Comment: I've just looked at your spreadsheet (posted this answer before seeing it) did you want an average of the values based on the dates?

Comment: After looking at your worksheet, I've amended the answer so that the date is compared to the headers (C1:N1) of the worksheet and the average is taken from the values in `C2:N2`

Comment: The OP wants the average of only 12 months, so use AverageIfs: `=AVERAGEIFS(C2:N2,$C$1:$N$1,">="&A2,$C$1:$N$1,"<"&A2+365)`

Comment: I LOVE YOU PEOPLE.  Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks, @Scott,  I was working simply to the columns, in that case it may need to extend to the very end of the populated table (column Q) so: `=AVERAGEIFS(C2:Q2,$C$1:$Q$1,">="&A2,$C$1:$Q$1,"<"&A2+365)`